# (T/F question) if $\mathbb{E}|X_n|\to 0$, then $\phi_n(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n})\to 1.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables.

> True or false? if $\mathbb{E}|X_n|\to 0$, then $\phi_n(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n})\to 1.$

I believe the answer is no (since convergence in $L_1$   does not imply convergence  in distribution in general). I have checked some discrete rv's, but they didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Convergence in $L_1$ *does* imply convergence in distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E|X_n| \to 0$ implies $X_n \to 0$ in probability, hence also in distribution. This implies $Ee^{itX_n} \to 1$ for all  real $t$.

Alternatively, use the fact that $|Ee^{itX_n}-1|\leq E|e^{itX_n}-1| \leq E|tX_n| \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. The "alternatively" part is very enlighting, also.

Comment: One note: $|e^z-1|\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^n}{n!}\leqslant  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z|^n=\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}\leqslant 2|z|$ for $|z|\leqslant 1/2.$